# Javascript countdown timer with a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I'm trying to create a countdown timer for each result in a PHP array, where one clicks on the link and it keeps track of each timer separately.  So far I have it working for the first result, but since I'm grabbing the element by ID, I'm having problems.  I realize that I need to get the element by class but I'm still too noobish and this is just what I have so far.

Also, if you click the link multiple times the countdown multiplies itself each time.  I could hide the link after click but there's probably a better solution.  I'm sure the code is messy and also I might be going about this completely wrong!  Thanks for any help.

```
    <script>
var mins = 10;
var secs = 0;
var timer;

function start(){
    timer = setInterval('update()', 1000);
        }

function update(){
    var timeField = document.getElementById('time');
    if(secs == 0){
        if(mins == 0){
    timeField.innerHTML = "Ready";
    clearInterval(timer);
    return;
                        }
mins--;
secs=59;
                    } 
else {
    secs--;
        }
    if(secs<10){
    timeField.innerHTML = mins + ":0" + secs;
    } 
    else {
    timeField.innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs;
    }
}
</script>
```

And the PHP:

```
    <?php
require ('info.php');
// database connection info
$conn = mysql_connect($sql_server,$username,$password) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

$db = mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$i = 0;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM faucet";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM faucet WHERE time BETWEEN 0 AND 29 ORDER BY faucet ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

    echo "<div style=\"margin:5px 0 5px 0;\"><h3>Continuous and Other Faucets</h3></div>";
    echo "<div id=\"container\" style=\"clear:both; margin-top:10px;\"><div id=\"row\"><div id=\"left\" class=\"faucetg\">Faucet</div><div id=\"middle\" class=\"faucetg\">Dispense</div><div id=\"middle\" class=\"faucetg\">Time</div><div id=\"middle\" class=\"faucetg\">Type</div><div id=\"right\" class=\"faucetg\">Status</div></div></div>";

// while there are rows to be fetched...
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dmin = $list['dmin']/100;
    $dmax = $list['dmax']/100;
   // echo data
    if ($i&1) {
echo "<div id=\"container\" style=\"clear:left;\"><div id=\"row\"><div id=\"left\" class=\"faucet\"><a onclick=\"start()\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"" . $list['url'] . "\">" . $list['faucet'] . "</a></div><div id=\"middle\" class=\"faucet\">" . $dmin . " - " . $dmax . " uBTC</div><div id=\"middle\" class=\"faucet\">" . $list['time'] . " minutes</div><div id=\"middle\" class=\"faucet\">" . $list['type'] . "</div><div id=\"right\" class=\"faucet\">" . $list['status'] . "<span id=\"time\" style='float:right;'>Ready</span></div></div></div>";
}
else {
echo "<div id=\"container\" style=\"clear:left;\"><div id=\"row\"><div id=\"left\" class=\"faucetl\"><a onclick=\"start()\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"" . $list['url'] . "\">" . $list['faucet'] . "</a></div><div id=\"middle\" class=\"faucetl\">" . $dmin . " - " . $dmax . " uBTC</div><div id=\"middle\" class=\"faucetl\">" . $list['time'] . " minutes</div><div id=\"middle\" class=\"faucetl\">" . $list['type'] . "</div><div id=\"right\" class=\"faucetl\">" . $list['status'] . "<span id=\"time\" style='float:right;'>Ready</span></div></div></div>";
}  
  $i++;
} // end while
?>
```

Comment: Unreadable !, please be well-written

Comment: Rewrite the code to be easier to read. jsbeautifier.org can help.